# Shell script erroring out due to supposed MySQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I've written a PHP script that resets a customer's password for my web application (Magento):

```
$write->query("update customer_entity_varchar set value='$password'
where entity_id=$customer_id and attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute 
where attribute_code='password_hash' and entity_type=1)");
```

However, when I try to execute from the shell:

```
php script.php
```

It produces the following error:

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:
    Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
    check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near 'and attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code' at line 1' in /chroot/home/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

NOTE: Variables are previously defined in beginning of script but I did not list them here as I felt they were extraneous.

Comment: what you get if you print the entire query ?

Comment: Great question, let me log it and see.

Comment: maybe the problem is the only one without quotes? entity_id=$customer_id and a

Comment: My guess is `$customer_id` is not holding a value. Note a parametrized prepared statement would prevent problems such as this.

Comment: $customer_id was indeed not holding a value. Thank you Abhik Chakraborty for the logging tip and Mike Brant for the attention to detail. I should have provided the variables - they would have helped. Should I close the question as it was solved with the help of comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem was solved with comments, here is how I turned on logging:

I stored the query as a variable: $query

```
    $query = "update customer_entity_varchar set value='$password' where entity_id=$customer_ID and attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code='password_hash' and entity_type_id=1)";
    $write->query($query);

    $file = 'query.txt';
    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    // Append a new person to the file
    $current .= $query . "\n";
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
```